# Questions about Visual Studio project files

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, file, project

What is the minimal set of files after creating a project in Visual Studio (2010) that You have to send to somebody who uses a different compiler ? (for example the Debug folder isn't necessary, but what about .vcxproj.user file or other ?)
What are .obj files?
What kind of information is displayed in "watch" and "call stack" windows during debugging ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only files you absolutely need to send someone are the source files and the project file. The source files will usually be `*.c` or `*.h` files, but could include others, like resources.

As far as the other files go, each of them does something slightly different. The full list, as of VS2013, is found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3awe4781.aspx). Most of them are generated by compiling and linking, or by opening the project in the IDE. A quick way to tell them apart is to do a Clean Solution, which should delete and intermediate files.

The `obj` files are intermediate files use during linking, and don't need to be packaged. In fact, nothing in the build or output folders needs to be included, as they'll all get rebuilt. The information that's used at debugging is mostly pulled from the `obj` and `pdb` files, which are both created each time you build.